# In Python what is it called when you use enclose a variable between 2 plus signs?

Tags: python, variables

What is it called when you use the plus signs to pull a variable into a string?

Example 1:

```
variable = "stuff"
print "I would like to print "+variable+" "
```

and why would that be used vs

Example 2:

```
variable = "stuff"
print "I would like to print %s" % variable
```

I'm new to the whole programming thing and this site, please forgive my ignorance and correct me if I'm lacking in proper etiquette.

Comment: If it helps, think of doing `"foo" + variable + "bar"` as first adding together the string "foo" and the variable, then adding the result of that with "bar". It's just like normal addition in math, except that instead of producing a number, you produce a string.

Comment: It's called string concatenation, represented by `+`.  string1 + string2 + string3.  You could keep going with + string4 + string5 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *concatenating strings*, not putting anything between two `+` signs. Compare this to adding up numbers:

```
4 + 5 + 6
```

This doesn't do anything special to the `5` there, that's just a sum of `(4 + 5) + 6`. Your expression is simply adding a value to a string, then adding another string.

You should use string formatting wherever possible, because it is more readable and gives you more flexibility. Consider learning about [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), a more consistent and more powerful version of string formatting:

```
variable = "stuff"
print "I would like to print {}".format(variable)

mapping = {'answer': 42, 'interest': 0.815}
print '''\
The answer to the ultimate question: {m[answer]:>10d}
Rate: {m[interest]:03.2%}!'''.format(m=mapping)
```

Demo:

```
>>> variable = "stuff"
>>> print "I would like to print {}".format(variable)
I would like to print stuff
>>> mapping = {'answer': 42, 'interest': 0.815}
>>> print '''\
... The answer to the ultimate question: {m[answer]:>10d}
... Rate: {m[interest]:03.2%}!'''.format(m=mapping)
The answer to the ultimate question:         42
Rate: 81.50%!
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be for when you're combining two things together? 

str1 = "Hello"
str2 = "World"
str1 + str 2 
and having that output hello world?

That's still concatenating?

Comment: @P0LYmath: yes, and the next `+` combines the *next* string to the result of the first concatenation. Just like `4 + 5 + 6` is a sum.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` (plus sign) is actually an overloaded operator. It works for addition like when you sum two integers (`1+1`) but it also works for strings. Actually you are not required to use it at both sides of the variable you want to "sum" (concatenate) with a string in order for this to work, you are only concatenating an additional empty space to the end of the printed string.

Some examples:

```
print 1 + 1 #this prints 2

str = "a"
print str + "b" #this prints ab

print 1 + "b" #this will error as python doesn't know by default how to "sum" an integer to a string
```

Note how the behaviour of adding two integers is fundamentally different from concatenating two strings. If you do `"1"+"1"` you won't get the string `"2"`, you get the string `"11"`. That's what overloading is all about.

Back to your example:

```
variable = "stuff" #this is a string
print "I would like to print "+variable+" "
```

here both `"I would like to print "` and `" "` are strings.
You are creating the first string in place, then adding the string inside `variable` to it.
Later you add yet another string to it, this time a string containing just a "space" character.
The resulting string is what gets printed.